# UiAutomatorTestCase extends InstrumentationTestCase?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I tried uiautomator tools on JB ..
After I configured the attachment source code for uiautomator (android sdk/sources/android-18) with Android source in Eclipse , I had this problem: I declared

```
public class UiAutomatorTestCase extends InstrumentationTestCase {...}.
```

However, referring to the SDK document, it should inherit from TestCase:

```
public class UiAutomatorTestCase extends TestCase {...}.
```

my question is:

- which inherited relationship is correct ?
- how can I attach the source code in Eclipse with the uiautomator library.
- How can I normal android api in uiautomator, such as startService(), broadcast , content provide, etc...

Answer (score 0):

answers in same order

1. public class UiAutomatorTestCase extends TestCase
2. compile UiAutomator source and create a jar file using jar utility
3. just import android.(remember you added android.jar as external jar while creating UiAutomator project)